# Silverstripe TTF file upload

Tags: file, upload, silverstripe, truetype

I'm trying to have a upload field to upload TTF file to my website. 
But when trying to upload it fails - it says **forbidden**.

How can I have upload field to upload just TTF files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell `File` class to allow that file type by adding it to the config, e.g. in *mysite/_config/config.yml*:

```
File:
  allowed_extensions:
    - ttf
```

You'll also have to whitelist it in your */assets/.htaccess*